# Programming in C - count occurences of a char element from structure with function

Tags: c, counter

I have problem with a function. I have a structure with student information as name, id number, marks etc. I am able to read and print all needed, but the problem is when i want to count the input equal names. For example if I enter to count name Iva, and it is present 3 times, to count 3. It returns 0 for what i used till now. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
char name [31];
char ID[11];//personal code
long FN;//student number

};

int BrS;
student MasStud[35]; //array for number of students

char bf[5];

void readStud(student *st){
int i;
printf("-------------------\n");
printf("Enter name of a student:\n"); gets_s(st->name);
printf("Enter ID");gets_s(st->ID);
printf("Enter FN:"); scanf_s("%ld",&st->FN);

gets_s(bf); 
}

void CountStudName(student*st){
        int count, j, n, i;
        char name1[31];
  int FreqArr[31];
        strcpy(st->name,name1);

  printf("Search name occurrence: "); gets(name1);

  for (i=0; i<BrS; i++)
      FreqArr[i]=-1;
  count=1;
  for (j=i+1;j<BrS;j++)
  {
      if (strcmp(st->name,name1)==0)j ++;
      count++;
      FreqArr[j]=count;

  }

 printf("The searched name is %d times present\n", count);

}


void main() {
    int i;

    printf("Enter number of students:"); scanf_s("%d",&BrS);
    gets_s(bf);
    printf("-------------------\n");
    for (i=0; i<BrS;i++) readStud(&MasStud[i]);
    printf("-------------------\n");
    CountStudName(&MasStud[i]);


    _getch();
}
```

Thank you in advance for you kind help.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using, but this code won't compile at [online GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler). First error is: `main.c:14:1: error: unknown type name ‘student’
 student MasStud[35]; //array for number of students`.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am using Visual c++ 2010 and is not giving this error

Comment: Compiler should be telling you about the error in [`gets_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gets-s-getws-s?view=vs-2019) – not enough arguments. Strangely you also use the obsolete function `gets`. Please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) There are numerous syntax errors in this code, please address what the compiler tells you.

Comment: You are also mixing the use of `scanf_s()` with `gets_s()` and this will lead to trouble. Stick to one input method. This question applies: [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: Please do not post "answers" which are intended to update a question. Instead, please **edit the question** using the `edit` button just below the tags to make the changes you wish to make. At the moment there's a pending edit so you'll have to either accept or reject the pending edit before making further changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should know VS will make a `.cpp` empty project for you by default and if you don't make `.c` project you will not receive many errors which are important.(I think you are using `.cpp`)

if you want to use `student` instead of `struct student` you should use `typedef`(if you code in `.cpp` projects you won't receive any error for this mistake.

```
 typedef struct student {
    char name[31];
    char ID[11];//personal code
    long FN;//student number

}student;
```

also you need to send two argument to `gets` look `char*_Buffer` and `rsize_t _Size`.you are only sending one ,but anyway using `gets` is not safe use `fgets` or `scanf` like below:

```
scanf("%31s",st->name)//this will prevent buffer overflow
```

as for your `CountStudName` function note when you call it , you have already traverse array `MasStud` here `for (i=0; i<BrS;i++)` . so when you send `CountStudName(&MasStud[i]);` to function nothing special is stored in that element.

I have rewrote this function to take a name and search for it and print how many students have that name:

```
void CountStudName(student* st) {
    int count, j, n, i;
    char name1[31];
    printf("Search name occurrence: "); 
    scanf("%31s", name1);
    count = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < BrS; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(st[j].name, name1) == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("The searched name is %d times present\n", count);

}
```

and you should call it like this in `main`: `CountStudName(MasStud);`